# When initializing in C# constructors what's better: initializer lists or assignment?

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization, variable-assignment

Class A uses an initializer list to set the member to the paramter value, while Class B uses assignment within the constructor's body.

Can anyone give any reason to prefer one over the other as long as I'm consistent?

```
class A
{
    String _filename;

    A(String filename) : _filename(filename)
    {
    }
}
```

```
class B
{
    String _filename;

    B(String filename)
    {
        _filename = filename;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The first one is not legal in C#.  The only two items that can appear after the colon in a constructor are `base` and `this`.

So I'd go with the second one.

Comment: Thank you, coming from C++ I was wondering whether Syntax A (member initialization list) was viable for C# too.

Answer (score 19):

Did you mean C++ instead of C#?

For C++, initializer lists are better than assignment for a couple of reasons:

- For POD types (int, float, etc..), the optimizer can often do a more efficient memcpy behind the scenes when you provide initializers for the data.
- For non-POD types (objects), you gain efficiency by only doing one construction. With assignment in the constructor, the compiler must first construct your object, then assign it in a separate step (this applies to POD types as well).

Answer (score 12):

As of [C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#constructors), there is a way to streamline this with expression bodies:

```
A(String filename) => _filename = filename;
```

(Looks better with two fields though):

```
A(String filename, String extension) => (_filename, _extension) = (filename, extension);
```

Answer (score 1):

C# has a feature called [Object Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer). You can provide values which the compiler will use to initialize the specified members, and call the default constructor. For this to work you need to have a public default constructor.